# add_custom_command apparently fails silently after moving target declaration

Tags: cmake

I've been caught out by an add_custom_command w/target declaration problem and present it here. Below are two CMake source trees, the first one runs the custom command while the second version does not.

QQ. I expected the two trees to be (roughly equivalent) - why would the latter skip running the custom command?

---

**V1: Building generates myFile.txt**

```
# ~/CMakeLists.txt
project(myProj)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

add_subdirectory(myDir)
```

```
# ~/myDir/CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(myExe)    # ***Declare target here***

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT myFile.txt
  COMMAND touch myFile.txt
  DEPENDS myFile.txt
)

target_sources(myExe PRIVATE myFile.txt)
```

---

**V2: Building doesn't generate a myFile.txt**

```
# ~/myDir/CMakeLists.txt
project(myProj)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

add_executable(myExe)    # ***Declare target here***
add_subdirectory(myDir)
```

```
# ~/myDir/CMakeLists.txt
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT myFile.txt
  COMMAND touch myFile.txt
  DEPENDS myFile.txt
)

target_sources(myExe PRIVATE myFile.txt)
```

I've been tearing my hair out and didn't turn up much after skimming the reference.  Cheers

Comment: Just a note... `cmake_minimum_required` must always come _before_ `project`. It's not the cause of the present bug, but it will cause other bugs...

Answer (score 1):

This is an unfortunate limitation of CMake, but it is documented. You can only attach generated source files to targets created in the *same* directory:

> This defines a command to generate specified `OUTPUT` file(s). **A target created in the same directory** (`CMakeLists.txt` file) that specifies any output of the custom command as a source file is given a rule to generate the file using the command at build time.

Emphasis mine. See the original documentation here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html

You can work around this by using OBJECT libraries, like so:

```
# ./myDir/CMakeLists.txt
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT myFile.cpp
  COMMAND touch myFile.cpp
  # The command doesn't depend on itself.
)

add_library(myExeObj OBJECT myFile.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myExe PRIVATE myExeObj)
```

Comment: thanks although this doesn't seem to work around the problem i.e. I still have to declare myExe in the original CMakeLists.txt.  It looks like there;s some canonical workaround using the add_custom_target command

Comment: @DavidMcCabe - this approach allows you to define `myExe` in either CMakeLists.txt. I'm not sure I understand your comment. You definitely don't need `add_custom_target` for this scenario.